# Can structures have the type `Card*`? (Example from book)

Tags: c++, pointers, syntax, typedef

My book says

```
typedef Card* Cardptr;
```

"defines the new type name `Cardptr` as a synonym for type `Card*`." I see that the `*` symbol modifies only `Cardptr` and that other synonyms if there were any more, are not modified by the `*` symbol. This is confusing to me. My book makes it seem like the actual structure type is `Card*`, which makes me think that other synonyms would have the type `Card*` as in

```
typedef Card* Cardptr, n;
```

where `n` would also have the type `Card*`. Wouldn't it be clearer if they moved `*` symbol like this?

```
typedef Card *Cardptr, n;
```

That way, you would know that the type is actually `Card`, that `Cardptr` is simply a pointer to it, and that `n` is not a pointer. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Prefer [type aliases](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) to typedefs. Chances are you don't even need the typedef in C++. Structures are classes in C++, they are user-defined types so they can't be of some type.

Comment: If you think `typedef Card* Cardptr, n;` is ugly, wait until you try to apply it to a function pointer. You're better off placing them on separate lines for readability if nothing else.

Comment: Note on the last bit: "Why?" `typedef`s are interpretted much the same as a variable definition (In C at any rate and I have yet to see anything in C++ that differs) . `Card *Cardptr, n;` defines two variables: a pointer to `Card` `Cardptr` and a `Card` `n`. Slapping `typedef` in front defines two types: `Cardptr` as a pointer to `Card` and `n` as a `Card`

Comment: _"Wouldn't it be clearer if they moved * symbol ..."_ No it won't.  To make it clearer, break it into two lines: `typedef Card* Cardptr;<newline>typedef Card n;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ generally does not care about whitespaces, so the two following statements are seen as identical by the compiler:

```
typedef Card* Cardptr;
typedef Card *Cardptr;
```

Similarly, the three declarations

```
int* a;
int *a;
int * a;
```

are indistinguishable.

---

> Wouldn't it be clearer if they moved `*` [so] you would know that the type is actually `Card`, that `Cardptr` is simply a pointer to it, and that `n` is not a pointer. What is the reason for this?

The way a coder writes their declarations is only a matter of taste and style, and both are equally justifiable:

This would make me prefer `int *a` over `int* a`:

```
int* a,b; // declares and int* and an int; illogical, right?
```

This would make me prefer `int* a` over `int *a`:

```
int *a = 0; // a (an int*) is set to zero (a.k.a NULL), not *a; illogical, right?
```

Now, my advice: choose between those two forms and stick with it, consistently.

Comment: I'd also note that using statement don't have this problem, and attach the star to the type.